# Shopify Product variant dropdown not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, responsive-design, e-commerce, shopify

The product variable dropdowns on my Shopify store are unresponsive when viewed on a mobile device (iOS and Android). I am able to replicate the issue on my desktop using firefox's Responsive design mode.

Has anyone dealt with this issue or know of a process to begin troubleshooting it?

the website is 
https://www.historicalarmory.com/products/wyatt-earp-limited-edition-engraved-rifle

Any guidance is appreciated.

Patrick